# Accidental error in setting php_value in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-reporting

So when I currently view `phpinfo()` in PHP, my `error_reporting` is set to some number, which represents the sum of all the error constant values, right?
Let's say, I accidentally set the value of `error_reporting` to some weird value by accident in .htaccess for example:

1. -1
2. Value that is bigger than E_ALL (32768 for example, if I'm correct)
3. When setting it with a string, I do a typo `(**E_AL** & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED)` - typo in E_ALL

What would happen, would it be set to some default value? Or from php.ini? I tried setting all the values above and they all were set in the `Local Value` without any problems.
I'm curious what will happen with any other value as well, will it default to php.ini or what?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses bitwise operators to determine whether the error level should be reported.. so whatever your integers value is as binary it would bitwise & to see if the error is reported.

E.g.
if E_DEPRECATED were (not saying this is accurate):  01, E_WARNING is 10, E_NOTICE is 100, using E_DEPRECATED | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE would give the binary 111, thus when an error is reported, like E_WARNING, it would take the value set, and bitwise & it to determine whether the report is displayed:

111 & 010 = True, so the error would be reported.

if you just used E_DEPRECATED | E_NOTICE, the binary is 101, so 101 & 010 = False, so the error won't be reported.

Each of these binaries can be converted to base10, 01 = 1, 10 = 2, 100 = 4 etc.

So if you were curious as to which errors would be reported with your random integer you can do:

`int & E_WARNING` in your PHP parser, if its True then the error will be shown, if its FALSE then the error will be ignored.

This is a good convention to learn, as its very useful when implementing logging on your application too, you can use the same system, and so you don't have to implement a long switch or if .. elseif .. block to determine whether a log level should be logged or not according to config.

```
  /**
   * Determines whether this message should be logged based on the provided type and the set threshold
   * @access protected
   * @param  int $type
   * @param  string   $name name of the log to check.
   * @return boolean
   */
  protected function should_log($type,$name='default') {
    return (bool) ($this->getConfig($name)->threshold & $type);
  }
```

so the threshold would be a binary number in your config (which uses constants for readability) then it bitwises & against the provided log type which returns True or False to determine whether to log the message to the logger by name `$name`... much more optimised.

Comment: Thank you very much, the bitwise & between my current error setting and active error makes sense, that helped me understand more how it works.  
However, I used the `error_reporting` more as an example, even though I want to understand how it works aswell.  
**The question I'm still curious about is**: what if we make a typo in `.htaccess` or in `php.ini`, what would happen? If it's in `.htaccess` will it take the value from `php.ini`? If there's a typo in `php.ini`, what then?  
I tried experimenting and the value changed only in the `Local Value`. So how does `php.ini` get it's values?